# MS Dynamics CRM users disappear

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-crm

Recently we came across quite a weird issue. The administrators say that once in a while they notice that user accounts in MS Dynamics CRM are lost .

When a new user is added to the system, the administrators add him/her to the Active Directory first. Then, they go to Dynamics CRM interface, then to `system configuration -> administration -> users` and add the new user to the CRM, add roles to this user, grant them relevant permissions.  Then the user is able to use a custom application, which connects to the Dynamics CRM via WCF.

After a while (few weeks or months) the user is unable to use the custom application because Dynamics CRM cannot authorise this user.  When administrators open the Dynamics CRM user management interface (`configuration -> administration -> users` ) and browse through the list of CRM users they **cannot find the user in the list**.  When they try to add the user to Dynamics CRM back, the CRM fails with the error message "*User already exists*". Moreover, the user still exists in the Active Directory.

The admins are very sure the user had been added to the CRM before he/she started to work. The only fact the the user was able to use the custom application normally says that the user had been indeed registered in the CRM.  How come the user is not listed in the CRM user management interface at all?

Have anyone faced any issues like that? Seen or heard of disappearing CRM users somewhere?

Any help is appreciated. Where can one start digging?

Comment: Have you checked the deactivated users?

Comment: James, they **are happened to be disabled**. I am sorry for being so late to respond. For some reason I didn't get any notification you had answered. Any ideas why? How could it have happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know which version of CRM you are using. But if you have access to database try search the user in table systemuser. When the administrators tried find the user which filter is active, maybe the user is deactivated like James Wood said. Try search in the deactivated users or make a advanced search and ignore the state of user.

Comment: Pedro, I'm collegue of Max, we still have this problem, we are using MSCRM 2011, and also tried to find users in deactivated, and through advanced search by your recommendations, no any positive results

Comment: If you have On-premisse check directly in database the table is systemuser.